# How to make URL of Web Activity as parameter in Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Web Activity in Azure Data Factory pipeline for Dev Environment.

It has URL, which has currently typed directly in ADF UI.
This URL is different in each Dev, Test and Prod environment.
URL are stored in Key Vault secret.

I have DevOps Pipeline, where ARM Template are deployed to Test and Prod.

1. How to make URL as parameter in Azure Data Factory? I already created WebUI parameter in pipeline, but don't know modify parameter file.
2. How to fetch URL from Key vault and set as parameter in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

Below link may be useful here, where it explains how to use Azure Key vault secrets in Azure Pipelines.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops

You can also reconsider your design. With in your Azure data factory pipeline itself  you can make API call to key vault to get URL depending on environment and use that URL in web activity.

Comment: Hi! What if your key vault account is different for each environment?